# How can create a singleton class with mock data with dragger 2?

Tags: java, android, dragger

Hi I want know if is possible create a singleton with mockdata and with dragger

I know the standard code for do it without dragger 2

```
public class Singleton {
    private Singleton() { }

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

Here I know where to put the array list with the data for mock, but how can do it with dagger where is the setup function or similar for put the ArrayList with the data, and how can call.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a method in one of your modules and annotate it with @Singleton annotation. For example:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    MockData provideMockData() {
       return new MockData(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    }

    @Provides
    OtherClass provideOtherClass(MockData mockData) {
       return new OtherClass(mockData);
    }
}

public class MockData {

    private List<String> list;

    public MockData(List<String> list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Check the section "Singletons and Scoped Bindings" in
https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html

Comment: And how can get the list in the other class?

Comment: Do you mean how to get the MockData instance in other classes?

Comment: You can use it as a field in other classes annotating it with @Inject or you can create other provider and get MockData as parameter. I change the example